# DurandalJS - Why are transitions not starting right away when a user navigates

Tags: durandal

Could someone explain why the transitions (at least the default one - entrance) are not starting right away when a user clicks on a link (navigate) with Durandal?

In other words, do we need two mechanisms (loader animation + transition) to indicate that there is an action underway (ex. ajax call inside the activate method).

I'm sure there's a good reason, or maybe I just have to modify the entrance transition?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Durandal's transitions run once the activate function resolves. I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281313/starting-transitions-before-activate-resolves) where I enumerated some of the possible solutions that I found which worked for my situation specifically:

- Manually animate away every view in its deactivate() and animate it back in via its viewAttached()
- Bind the .page-host div's visibility to router.isNavigating (using a custom binding to handle the transition such as the fadeVisible example from the knockout site)
- Manually subscribe to router.isNavigating and run custom logic when it changes

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not [compress](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/) your entire application then the first process will be requirejs downloading the next amd module and then downloading the appropriate view.

The next step is durandal calling activate on your module.  Activate if it returns a [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) then it will wait for the deferred to complete.

Once activate is complete then the transition is called.  The transition is responsible for swapping out the old view for the new one.

So, if its taking a while to kick off the transition its probably because its lagging in downloading your module and view.. or your activate method is taking a bit of time to finish.

Comment: Thanks Evan! I know all that. The question is: why don't the transition serve **also** to indicate that there is a action (ajax) ongoing... Instead of calling the transition when the activate is completed, the deferred would be use as to when the transition starts and when it ends... with that said, I may well be out of scope and I will probably remove this question soon ;-)

Comment: You can display a spinner immediately after they click the link and have it display until the new view is shown.  If that is what your trying to do..?

Comment: Instead of doing two things (displaying a spinner and executing a transition) I would prefer to use the transition only: it would span trough all the request instead of firing when the request is done...  with the help of promises.